# How do I reference the AJAX request object inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I use `$.ajax()` method from `JQuery` to do some POST requests, and inside its `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }` callback, I want to implement a simple retry mechanism with timeout, e.g.

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax(myReqOptions);
}, 3000);
```

`myReqOptions` here needs to be the options object I define in `$.ajax()` to make this work. Is there a convenient way to reference this object other than setting a temp variable before calling the timeout, like this:

```
myReqOptions = this;
timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax(myReqOptions);
}, 3000);
```

`this` here refers to the owner of the `error` callback, which is the object I define in `$.ajax()`.

Comment: "*the object I define in `$.ajax`*" - I don't see any object (literal?) definition, you are only using that `myReq` variable? You can reference that variable from your error callback as well.

Comment: You could use $.proxy or Function.bind, but it's simpler to just use that temporary variable.

Comment: @Bergi `this` in this case is the options object passed to the original `$.ajax` that we are in the error handler of.

Comment: Oh, that code is the error callback body already? Then it should be fine (only use a local variable, `var myReq = …`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temp variable is fine. To shorten the call a littlebit, you can use the [`bind` function method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
timeout = window.setTimeout($.ajax.bind($, this), 3000);
```

or, for compatibility with old browser (not using the ES5 shim), with [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
timeout = window.setTimeout($, "ajax", this), 3000);
```